# How to initiate a keyboard key click event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here I'm trying to override the default shortcuts of IE browser. I'm using IE8 for my application.

Let me give an example. I want to override a shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. The default function of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in IE is "Open the Page menu". I tried doing the following way, but I'm not able to override it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
 
document.onkeydown = printKeycode;
var isAlt = false;
 
function printKeycode(e) 
{
    //alert('11')
    var keycodeentered = window.event.keyCode;
    if(keycodeentered == 18) 
    {
        isAlt=true;
    }
 
    if(keycodeentered == 80 && isAlt == true)  // P keycode is 80
    {
        alert('Combination entered');
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    
    }
}
 
 </script>
```

But I'm not able to override the default functionality. My action is being triggered at the same time the default action is happening. Small observation is, I am able to prevent the default action of shortcuts using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> combination. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this here:
[Overriding Browser's Keyboard Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts)
or 
[Disable Internet Explorer shortcut keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130353/disable-internet-explorer-shortcut-keys)
or
[How can I disable Alt-Enter in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592847/how-can-i-disable-alt-enter-in-ie)